# Windows 7 PC getting unidentified network and no network access on 1 wifi

Tags: wireless, dell, access-point, network-discovery

Good afternoon guys.  I have a Dell precision 4800 Laptop which is most of the time hooked up to the LAN at the users desk.  Out on our production floor we have 4 Access Points, each on their own VLAN except for 1 which shares the 192.168.0.* network with the rest of the main domain.

When the user takes his laptop out to the Access Point and connects the computer says it is connected to an unidentified network and it gets an IP from the DHCP server successfully but it cannot see any other devices on the network.  The IP that it gets is the IP that he gets when connected to the LAN.

When he connects to another AP he gets his DHCP address for that VLAN (192.168.4.*) and is able to connect to the network and email and internet just fine.

When I take another computer out there to the floor and connect to the wifi it gets the same IP as if connected to the LAN and it works just fine.  Able to surf the web, connect to network drives, everything.

I tried netsh int ip reset and everything I can think of but this one PC, on this 1 network, will not connect properly and I am confused as hell.

All of the AP's are up to date with the latest firmware and they are all the same model, Pakedge W7

Comment: This question is off topic here, you can consider asking on [su].